# Codeigniter 2 shared hosting sub-directory installation

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I know this has been asked a lot of times before, but I did search a lot without finding an answer. So I'm hoping someone will help me out. I have a shared hosting and inside the public_html folder I wish to install my CI app. The sub-directory name is "hrms".

So I uploaded all the CI files to hrms. Now when I visit http://www.example.com/hrms/index.php/login/do_login I get the famous error `No input file specified.` I have tried with .htaccess file with several variations that I could find, but none have helped. The http://www.example.com/hrms/index.php is working, so I'm guessing all the config is all right.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is the .htaccess file a must, even if I intend to access the site via full URL?

==== .htaccess =====

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /hrms

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hrms/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hrms/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hrms/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you include your directory name in the htaccess before index.php ...

Comment: I guess not. Can you point me to a good sample .htaccess that will work in my case?

Comment: Can you put your hataccess code so I modify it

Comment: @Amir Done, please check.

Comment: DId you change your `$config['base_url']` ?
I removed my answer because you have it correct

Comment: $config['site_url'] = 'http://localhost/hrms'; $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/hrms';

Comment: I believe both are supposed to have a forward slash at the end. And potentially start with http:// or https:// also.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Added a slash at the end and still no change. By the way, it was working fine on local server. I did add http but it looks like the StackOverflow server is stripping it off.

Comment: Have you changed either of application or system folders to a different name?

Comment: Also check directory permission ?

Comment: @Amir In that case, shouldn't I get a different error message. The http://example.com/hrms/index.php is working, so I guess the directory permissions are all right. I also uploaded standalone scripts to this folder and they ran fine.

Comment: Have you removed index.php from `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`?

Comment: @PaulSkinner No, it's same as original setting.

Comment: @dotslash Try removing it. Can't see it making a difference, but as you've removed index.php in .htaccess it may cause a problem?

Comment: It's now `$config['index_page'] = '';` and still the same behavior.

Comment: My knowledge of .htaccess is a little sketchy, but is setting `RewriteBase /hrms` necessary?

Comment: Was just going to say that @PaulSkinner `RewriteBase /hrms` doesn't seem necessary as `RewriteRule` already has `/hrms`. Use `RewriteBase /` or comment that out.

Comment: It was suggested by someone, because I guess CI is not in root. but making it `RewriteBase /` has no effect. :(

Comment: @dotslash Try removing it entirely

Comment: worst case, enable logging and check the logs. `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace4`

Comment: Right, last one from me that I can think of:`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` Change this to each of the settings in turn listed in the comments above this setting to see if it helps.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Doesn't help. Thanks for trying. :)

Comment: One for luck, if your host is GoDaddy or just happens to work similarly, check this out: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much ado about nothing.

===== UPDATE =====

I've now discovered that the problem is with GoDaddy hosting (GoDaddy and CI have a hate-hate relationship, it seems). The trick is to define your index.php as index.php? (notice the question mark) in the config.php file.

Nevertheless, many thanks to everyone who put effort into it!

**Please note:** If you're fine with ugly URLs like http://www.example.com/index.php?/HomeController/myFunction and aren't using routing (like me for now), there is no need for the .htaccess file.

Comment: Really, I'm humbled by all the effort. Hopefully I'll keep getting such support in future. :)

Comment: No problem. If it's CodeIgniter based I'll always give it a look if you tag me :) (No promises on speed though...)